# How to simplify this C# repetitive code?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, refactoring

`GetTranslation` function returns a string.

`ExistsHelper` function returns the bool.

```
public static class ValidatorNotExistHelper
{
    public static string Country(int id)
    {
        return (!ExistsHelper.Country(id)) ? GetTranslation(ConfigTranslationCode.CountryNotExist) : string.Empty;
    }

    public static string State(int id)
    {
        return (!ExistsHelper.State(id)) ? ConfigTranslationCode.StateNotExist : string.Empty;
    }

    public static string City(int id)
    {
        return (!ExistsHelper.City(id)) ? ConfigTranslationCode.CityNotExist : string.Empty;
    }
}
```

As you may notice the code is being repeated, the conditional statement. Only the function at `ExistsHelper` and translation message is different. Any ideas would be appreciated.

**Edited:**

I may also have `Overloading`, for an example:

```
public static string City(int cityId, int stateId, int countryId)
{
     return (!ExistsHelper.City(cityId, stateId, countryId)) ? ConfigTranslationCode.CityNotExist : string.Empty;
}

public static string City(int cityId, int stateId)
{
     return (!ExistsHelper.City(cityId, stateId)) ? ConfigTranslationCode.CityNotExist : string.Empty;
}
```

Comment: If `ExistsHelper.City(id)` *exist* you return `string.Empty`. Is it right? How can I get *actual* `City`s name?

Comment: ExistsHelper.City(id) returns `boolean`. The `City name` is not important for this code. If the boolean value is true then the code returns error message otherwise returns empty string.

Answer (score 1):

You could pass in the function you to use for the existence check, like this:

```
public static class ValidatorNotExistHelper
{
    public static string Country(int id)
    {
        return IdToString(ExistsHelper.Country,
                          GetTranslation(ConfigTranslationCode.CountryNotExist), id);
    }

    public static string State(int id)
    {
        return IdToString(ExistsHelper.State,
                          ConfigTranslationCode.StateNotExist, id);
    }

    public static string City(int id)
    {
        return IdToString(ExistsHelper.City,
                          ConfigTranslationCode.CityNotExist, id);
    }

    private static string IdToString(Predicate<int> exists, string defaultValue, int id)
    {
        return (!exists(id)) ? defaultValue : string.Empty;
    }
}
```

This would successfully factor out some of the shared logic, at the expense of some added complexity.

If you've only got three of these methods I'd be tempted to leave them as they are. If you've got lots and will be adding more then this refactoring might be worthwhile.

Comment: I will have more than 20 functions, but within these I will also have the overloading. Maybe, I should modify my original question and mention about overloading...

Comment: Provided the overloading example to the original question.

Comment: @CoderAbsolute You _could_ have multiple versions of `IdToString` to cope with the overloads but it's starting to feel clunky

Answer (score 0):

you can simplify a little with generics but it will make your call more complicated

if you create an interface as

```
public interface IExists
{
    int id{get;}
}
```

and make sure all Comparable classes implement it
ie

```
public class City:IExists
```

you could then do

```
public static class ValidatorNotExistHelper<T>
      where T:IExists
{
    public static bool Exists(int id,IEnumerable<T> possibles)
    {
        return possibles.Any(p=>p.id == id);
    }
    public static string ValidateExists(int id,IEnumerable<T> possibles,string ErrorMessage)
    {
        return Exists(id,possibles) ? String.Empty : ErrorMessage;
    }
    //using lookup Enum
    public static bool Exists(ClassTypeEnum type, int id)
    {
        return Exists(id,Lookup.GetPossibles(type));
    }
    public static string ValidateExists(ClassTypeEnum type,int id)
    {
        return Exists(type,id) ? String.Empty : Lookup.GetError(type);
    }
}
//Enum based lookup
public static class Lookup<T>
      where T:IExists
[
     public IEnumerable<T> GetPossibles(ClassTypeEnum type)
     {
         switch(type)
         {
             case ClassTypeEnum.City:
                 return //source of Cities;
         }
     }
     public IEnumerable<T> GetError(ClassTypeEnum type)
     {
         switch(type)
         {
             case ClassTypeEnum.City:
                 return ConfigTranslationCode.CityNotExist;
         }
     }
?
```

Comment: After your answer am beginning to realize that maybe I am trying too hard to refactor where I may end up losing the simplicity?

Comment: it is always a trade off, generally unless you are doing Exactly the same thing its rarely worth it, and i mean same as the computer sees it not a human reading it

Comment: another option would be to add an Enum that contains city state etc, then use a lookup class that returns the error message and source of possible values from the enum

Comment: I have implemented Enum yesterday but ended up losing the `Overloading` functionality.  I may have Overload on City for an example `City(int countryId, int StateId)`.

Comment: the enum wouldn't prevent overloading, i've updated with an example

Comment: Not sure, how would I achieve if City has 3 overloads, for an example:
`City(id) //cityId or
City(int countryId, int stateId) or City(int stateId)`

Comment: In that case you would probably feed in a Preficate<City> then pass that in but getting seriously messy now

Comment: That was my initial thought as well. Maybe, I will have to live with what I have so far and needs no refactoring...